# A software library that draws a series of connected circles/nodes, trying to draw dependencies

Tags: library

I have a list of items and items they depend on. I want to visualize them between myself and my team. This is to visualize a series of dependencies on github. I looked online for software to do this but they all seem to cost money.

Is there some library I can use that would draw on a canvas... or *something* that lets me visualize this? All I need is something that will draw them for me, nothing fancy. I will take care of the rest of the stuff in terms of making sure connections exist and such.

Ideally it'd be JavaScript so I can throw this onto a simple web app and it'd be shared everywhere, but I'd also take a library from an existing language.

It should be easy to learn because this will be nothing more than an internal app that preferably can be made in less than a few hours.

I figure such a thing might not exist, so many some kind of library that lets me draw circles and lines and drag around a position/camera on a canvas would be my next best option.

An example of something close to what I'd be looking for: https://github.com/markitx/issue-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [visjs](https://visjs.org/examples/network/data/dynamicData.html) as a pure JS solution.

With R I'd use the [visNetwork](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/) Package to export dataframes (=tables) to JS-based plots (based on vis.js), but here are many other libraries.

Here is an example:

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,2), to = c(1,2,4,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
        visEdges(shadow = TRUE,
                 arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 2)),
                 color = list(color = "lightblue", highlight = "red")) %>%
        visLayout(randomSeed = 12) # to have always the same network
```

This produces

[image: smallnetwork]

but it is actually interactive graph.